# Do SQL tables benefit or need to have a unique ID column?

Tags: mysql, sql-server

In my experience almost all tables have a field called Id that is a unique primary key and indexed.  My question is if I'm not using this value anywhere and will never need this value what is the benefit of having it.

Here is my problem:

The database has these many-many relationship tables (often called map tables) that link two other tables together by their unique Ids.

ex rows:

Id= 1 MachineId= 1 UserId= 2

Id= 2 MachineId= 1 UserId= 3

The way the code stands today when it updates this table it removes all Users of a machine and then proceeds to add all of the current users back.  This is how they chose to remove old entries.  The problem is this inflates the Id column unnecessarily because you remove/add for every user even if nothings changed.  This happens by default every 90mins.

One solution to this is to fix the code to do things the right way.  Another solution is to just remove the Id field altogether.  Since we don't link to this table somewhere else and we don't use the Id value in code anywhere (we don't even pull it from the DB) why do we need it?

So back to my original question.  Is the Id field needed for something else?  Or does it provide some benefit that I would lose that I may want?

Comment: Your problem statement is unclear. `The problem is this inflates the Id column unnecessarily because you remove/add for every user even if nothings changed.`  - does this imply that you think you will run out of ID numbers eventually? Why is this an issue?

Comment: Not only will you run out of IDs, which obviously is an issue because you will get errors, but also, the index on the key will require extra space, and it takes extra time to update it on insertion and deletion, which -small as it may be- is a waste if the key is not used.

Comment: Yes GolezTrol is correct we are running out of Id numbers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it's not needed, and especially for those many-to-many relationships, it is perfectly acceptible to just not have them.

Those ids are especially useful if you have foreign key relations to that table, but even then, you can have foreign keys that consist of a unique combination of multiple columns, so even for foreign keys you don't strictly need them, although it is very much recommended to use single value keys for this purpose.

The added benefit of having a key you don't need, is that you don't need to add it, once you are going to need it. Hardly an excuse. :)

In case you want to google more info:

- Those many to many tables are often called a '[junction table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table)' or 'cross-reference table'.
- A 'meaningless' unique ID, often auto-numbered, is also called a '[surrogate key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key)'
- A key (including primary keys and foreign keys) that consists of multiple fields, is called a '[compound key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_key)'. '[Composite key](http://www.techopedia.com/definition/6572/composite-key)' is often used as a synonym, although Wikipedia has a slightly different definition.

Answer (score 3):

Technically, you don't NEED to have a unique id, but there are far too many situations where not having one will really screw you up. e.g. Consider an address book. You might assume that "firstname, lastname, address" is enough to identify someone, but consider "John Smith, 123 Main Street" and "John Smith, 123 Main Street" (John Junior). Obvious solution: add a "Jr." field, or add more to the key and keep hoping you won't ever get a duplicate.... or you just add an auto_increment ID field and be done with it. doesn't matter what other fields are duplicates across records, you KNOW the id field will be unique.

You can easily make a unique composite key if you'd like, but then if you need to set up a foreign key relationship, you'd have to duplicate ALL of those keys' fields in the foreign table.

e.g.

```
table A (
   p, q, r, s t -> char
   primary key (p, q, r, s, t)
)

table B (
   h, i, j, k -> whatever
   p, q, r, s, t -> char
   foreign key (p, q, r, s, t) -> A (p, q, r, s, t)
)
```

Now you've got your pqrst fields in two tables, and have to write them out, IN FULL, for every join operation. Whereas, if you had a simple single ID field:

```
table A (
    id -> primary key int
    p, q, r, s ,t
)

table B (
    h, i, j, k -> hwatever
    a_id -> int
    foreign key (a_id) -> A (id)
)
```

one simple int field carried between the two tables, v.s. `n` fields for every field in the composite key.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer:** In this case, you described in your question, the ID column is not necessary, you can drop it if you will and add a PK/Unique to the table which is built up using the IDs from the linked tables.

**Long answer** (with my personal opinion): The ID column was used to speed up queries which are using lots of joins (comparing an integer is mostly faster than comparing long strings), and to moderate the size of link tables and foreign key columns. Another usage is to add a unique identifier to those tables which laks simple real life identifiers (like log tables).

In some cases the ID column is just added because all tables contains an ID column.

You always have to consider that the ID column has any meaning or is it really necessary: if you have character codes (using only ASCII characters) with less than 4 charactes length, the code will be smaller than the INT ID column (INT is stored on 4 bytes, bigint on 8 bytes).

Another thing: Always add the name of the entity to the ID column (such as `PersonID`, `InvoiceID`) to make the queries and schema more readable. In my opinion, a column's name always should represent what it stores, the name `ID` is just not describes the value stored in the column, when `PersonID` does. Furthermore, you can (and should) use the same name in foreign keys.

In most cases in our time with the current hardwares, the ID columns are mostly complicates the databases (you always have to join several tables to get the business/natural key). Furthermore the ID has no meaning for the business. You can always consider to leave the ID column and use a natural key as primary key. (You could leave the ID column, when you have an ID as a PK and one more column defined as `unique` `not null`: for example: A table contains invoices: the PK could be the InvoiceNumber which is on the paper based invoice, rather than the ID, but if the database is responsible to generate that number, you have to use a sequence based column.)

The ID (or any machine generated identifier) is useful when you don't have simple natural keys to use (or you have natural keys, but they are too wide or the have to build up using several other columns), or the natural key us mutable, you have to have some king of uniq identifier (car's license plate number is one example).

Comment: I completely agree on using `PersonID` instead of just `ID` I don't agree about the natural keys. Updating keys with foreign keys is a bitch, and natural keys will need to be updated sooner or later. The idea about surrogate keys is that they are immutable. IMO for joins and foreign key relations, you should not use natural keys. In this question, natural keys aren't the issue, though. It's just a junction table with FKs to two surrogate keys.

Comment: Partially I agree with you, in some cases the natural key is mutable (see my last edit done while you wrote your comment), but in some cases it is not mutable. The easy way is to always add an ID column. BTW if the natural key is mutable, than that is not a key anymore -> it can not be used as PK or even as a unique.

Comment: I prefer PersonKey vs ID or PersonID.  Its a personal preference.  But when you have an EmployeeID (which is not a surrogate key, but rather an Identifier that an organization uses)...the "Key" suffix keeps things less ambiguous.

Comment: While it sometimes it is not needed........I have never regretted creating the extra surrogate key, but I have regretted NOT creating it.  By default, I create the extra surrogate key.....